# Firefox addon - how to listen to a text highlight event in a webpage

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am writing an addon which needs to do capture the no of times someone has highlighted any text on a webpage. Is there any way I can listen to this event?

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a particular event for this. But you can listen to the [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onmouseup) event and check whether the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) returned by [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) is not empty and/or whether it differs from the previous selection.

Comment: Thanks Felix! will try this out

Comment: The selection can of course be modified with the keyboard as well as the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a selection listener. The Source window (viewSource.js) does this so that it can keep the row and column number up-to-date.

Comment: Hi neil can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: For others interested see this topic here I will post solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216324/observe-for-highlight